# Format Exception- DateTime and hours

Tags: c#, formatting

I want to get the hours from the datetime. So if it is 1pm it will just be 1 if it is 10pm it will be 10. So no leading zero to be place on hours 1-9

So I tried to do this

```
DateTime test= DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("h"));
```

I get this

> System.FormatException was unhandled
>   Message=Input string was not in a
>   correct format.   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.DateTimeFormat.GetRealFormat(String
>   format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)
>          at System.DateTimeFormat.ExpandPredefinedFormat(String
>   format, DateTime& dateTime,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo& dtfi, TimeSpan&
>   offset)
>          at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime
>   dateTime, String format,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, TimeSpan
>   offset)
>          at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime
>   dateTime, String format,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)
>          at System.DateTime.ToString(String
>   format)
>          at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   C:\Users\chobo2\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line
>   21
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hSpecifier) (the "h" custom format specifier):

> If the "h" format specifier is used without other custom format specifiers, it is interpreted as a standard date and time format specifier and throws a FormatException. For more information about using a single format specifier, see Using Single Custom Format Specifiers later in this topic.

You can use the following ([as described](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers) in "Using Single Custom Format Specifiers)":

> To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as the only specifier in a format string (that is, to use the "d", "f", "F", "g", "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/" custom format specifier by itself), include a space before or after the specifier, or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the single custom date and time specifier.

So, you can do the following:

```
DateTime test= DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("{0:%h}")); // From the document, adds precision
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("%h")); // Will also work
```

Comment: Ya I found something about %h but did not understand why you needed it.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx

Comment: +1. Although shouldn't it be `Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("%h"));`?

Comment: @David Neale - both would work. The `0:` is a precision specifier, just in case.